# Can't control backlight; strange segfault

Tags: xorg, arch-linux, backlight

I'm using Arch Linux on my Packard Bell EasyNote TX86 (Intel HD Graphics, Core i5) and I can't control the backlight (it's always on max). xbacklight and writing to /sys/class/backlight does nothing. I tried

```
xrandr --output LVDS --set BACKLIGHT_CONTROL native
```

but it segfaults X with

```
Backtrace:
[   308.398] 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x3b) [0x80e685b]
[   308.398] 1: /usr/bin/X (0x8048000+0x64895) [0x80ac895]
[   308.398] 2: (vdso) (__kernel_rt_sigreturn+0x0) [0xb770140c]
[   308.398] 3: /usr/bin/X (0x8048000+0xbe860) [0x8106860]
[   308.398] 4: /usr/bin/X (0x8048000+0x23e57) [0x806be57]
[   308.398] 5: /usr/bin/X (0x8048000+0x1a135) [0x8062135]
[   308.398] 6: /lib/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main+0xe6) [0xb7442c76]
[   308.398] 7: /usr/bin/X (0x8048000+0x19d11) [0x8061d11]
[   308.398] Segmentation fault at address 0x48
[   308.398] 
Fatal server error:
[   308.398] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting
```

Ubuntu can't control it either, but Windows can. Any ideas? I'd love to use Linux full time but it eats my battery.

Comment: You should probably to post this instead on the [arch linux forums](http://bbs.archlinux.org) if you want a change to fix it.

Comment: I would suggest the same thing with @hesse. Also you can try different acpi settings, backlight is generally related to acpi.

[ACPI Modules @ ARCH Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ACPI_modules)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no longer a problem, the kernel has supported it for a while.

Answer (score 0):

I presume (hope) you're talking about keyboard backlight... in which case I used [Ktoso's](http://www.blog.project13.pl/index.php/fun/1163/g73-keayboard-backlight-scripts/) bash script script binded to a keyboard shortcut to get this working.

It worked for me in Arch but not in Ubuntu, but I no longer use Ubuntu so it's all good.

Comment: Actually I just realised you are definitely not talking about keyboard backlight... I'll leave my answer here just in case anyone thinks the same as me...

Answer (score 0):

While this is less of a fix and more of a patch..
I personally used the 1st answer by `Syzygy` [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13196/setpci-making-a-script-to-manually-change-brightness).
Bind all 3 of the scripts to certain key combos for easy adjustment.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue on my laptop with the past 2-3 versions of Ubuntu, but I've discovered a pretty quick fix. I have no idea if this'll work on Arch, but maybe it's worth a try?

Try editing `/etc/default/grub` and add following entry to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`:

`acpi_backlight=vendor`

So the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` would now look something like `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"`

(You could also pass this to Grub during boot if you just want to try it once.)